# How to get the device width usign Django built-in template tags?

Tags: django, django-templates

I've been googling about this, there are some tools like **Django responsive** and **Django responsive2** but these package are out of date.

Links:

Django responsive 2 https://pypi.org/project/django-responsive2/

Django resposnive [https://django-responsive.readthedocs.io/en/v0.2.0/Is there any way](https://django-responsive.readthedocs.io/en/v0.2.0/Is%20there%20any%20way)

I'm asking for a built-in template tag, not about how to take the device with and send it to the server.

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the reasons why you want to do it in the first place, **there is no built-in template tag for this**. The client has to forward its screen size (if it has a screen in the first place) or device info to the server for the server to know this.

To do so (yes I know you didn't ask for it), you can either infer from the user-agent, or use some JS to get the width of the device and send it to the server (which is what `django-responsive` does, and sends the device info via cookies).

I haven't tested nor extensively analyzed `django-responsive`, and but a quick glance and it seems to still be a valid solution to what you are looking for (you can access the width via `{{ device_info.width }}` in your templates using this package).